# Cannot compare two enums if there is at least one case with associated value

Tags: swift, enums, swift2

Suppose I have:

```
enum Type {
    case A
    case B
}
```

Now I can compare them:

```
let enums = [Type.A, Type.B]

if enums[1] == Type.A {  //true }
```

Everything is fine unless I add another case with associated value:

```
case C(String)
```

Now I have an error:

> Binary operator `==` cannot be applied to two `Type` operands.

How to do this to make it working?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as of Xcode 7 beta 4 you have to implement your own `==` function yourself since the compiler can no longer infer an equality operation. Especially for `Type.C`: should it also check for equality of the associated value?

Examples of a logical/static implementation:

```
// comparing associated values
func ==(t1: Type, t2: Type) -> Bool {
    switch (t1, t2) {
    case (.A, .A): return true
    case (.B, .B): return true
    case (.C(let x), .C(let y)) where x == y: return true
    default: return false
    }
}

// without comparing
func ==(t1: Type, t2: Type) -> Bool {
    switch (t1, t2) {
    case (.A, .A): return true
    case (.B, .B): return true
    case (.C, .C): return true
    default: return false
    }
}
```

An easier way would be to convert it into a `String` (using reflection). This would be a dynamic approach/solution but it could change over time especially for own types (no longterm solution):

```
// you "have to" compare associated values
func ==(t1: Type, t2: Type) -> Bool {
    return String(t1) == String(t2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to do in Swift 4.2

```
enum SomeType: Equatable {
    case a
    case b
    case c(String)
}

let enums = [SomeType.a, SomeType.b, SomeType.c("Some string")]

if enums[1] == SomeType.b {  print("true") }
```

Answer (score -2):

You'll have to implement func == for the enum type. There are examples on stackoverflow showing you how to do it with one line of code per case.